# How to allow only certain users access to certain fields of a node?

Tags: users

I have product information on my site. Only some users can view pricing for certain suppliers. So each product has a supplier field, which is a node entity reference to an instance of a "supplier" content type.

When User A logs in, who only has access to Products Offered by Supplier B, he must only see the "cost price" of items that he is linked to. This link is currently accomplished using a Profile Field, which is private and set by administrators.

What is the best way to now restricting users based on this relationship. The end result would be that certain users see the full node with the cost price, while others will see everything except the cost price.

How can I get this right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to override [hook_field_access](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_access/7). This is the only way I could easily create custom code that checks the current entity and compares it to a profile field of a user. And seeing as the entire entity is passed along, there is no need to do further node_load queries. I.e. It's pretty fast!

Answer (score 1):

Install [Field Permission](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions) module. In this module you can set permission on every filed of content types for different roles.

---

You can also modify [hook_field_display_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_display_alter/7)  to check for the user and the field id and see if the user is allowed or not. you should copy this in to your template file.

Comment: yes, but not per user, which is my problem. i will only have one role, and that is authenticated user.

Comment: create new role, assign that role to your specific users. What is your problem with creating role?

Comment: I updated the answer

Comment: If I have 5000 suppliers, that would mean 5000 roles, which is not what roles was designed for.

Comment: that is not 5000 roles, there is only 1 role, called it BANNED_USER and assign this role to any one you want

Comment: Basically what I am looking for is hook_node_access, but for fields. Something like hook_field_access

Comment: And I'll be damned, hook_field_access exists!

Comment: Sorry I copied the answer of some thing else in here. I corrected the asnwer

Comment: From what I know hook_field_access is for editing not viewing, check this hook and also `field_display_alter`